# how to build my project with NuGet ArmDot msbuild?

Tags: vb.net, nuget

i try to obfuscation my project by ArmDot and i do all steps but i have problem in compile with build armdot i see in site armdot https://www.armdot.com/docs/tutorial.html#prepare-the-project
they are said and i dont understand this step where i can put this code to any file ?
(It is easy to add obfuscation to the build process. Ensure that the ArmDot.Engine.MSBuildTasks NuGet package is added to the project.

This package provides an MSBuild task that obfuscates assemblies by ArmDot after they have been built.

Close the solution in Visual Studio, and add the task to the end of the project file right before :)

```
<Target Name="Protect" AfterTargets="AfterCompile" BeforeTargets="BeforePublish">

  <ItemGroup>
 <Assemblies Include="$(ProjectDir)$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ArmDot.Engine.MSBuildTasks.ObfuscateTask
Inputs="@(Assemblies)"

ReferencePaths="@(_ResolveAssemblyReferenceResolvedFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)')"

SkipAlreadyObfuscatedAssemblies="true"

  />

</Target>
```